# tex4ht when using \hspace with star in mathjax mode

Tags: spacing, tex4ht

This MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 p_{i-1} &= -(p_{i})' - \theta p_i   \hspace*{5pt} \text{if} \hspace{10pt} i=n
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Compiles with no problem in pdflatex and produces

[image]

But when compiling using

```
make4ht  -ulm default  foo.tex "mathjax,htm" "-cunihtf -utf8"
```

No error is generated by HTML looks like this

[image]

Removing the star from `\hspace` then it works OK. So for now, I removed the star from `\hspace`.

The raw HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='foo.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='foo.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 7 --><p class='noindent'>\begin {align*}  p_{i-1} &amp;= -(p_{i})' - \theta p_i \hspace *{5pt} \text {if} \hspace {10pt} i=n  \end {align*}
</p>  
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Is this a tex4ht issue or mathjax? Does one need to add special configuration to tex4ht mathjax .cfg to avoid this error?

TL 2022

Comment: it is an issue with _your_ code, if you use mathjax option it is your responsibility to use markup understood by mathjax. You could use `\quad` instead of `\hspace*{...`  or for that matter you could use `\hspace` as the `*`does nothing useful in math mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems. First one is that the `*` character is separated from `\hspace` in the HTML output, which is caused by the process of detokenization. But even if we try to fix that and remove the spurious space, it doesn't help. MathJax doesn't know this command, so it doesn't display your equation. I wasn't even able to define the starred commands, it seems that it isn't possible to define them easily for MathJax.

I would use a custom command instead. I've wrote about [various means how to configure MathJax](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Howto.html#mathjax-latex-mode) recently, so please read this section.

The interesting change in TeX4ht sources is that it is now possible to include file with macro definitions to MathJax. This way, you can have a file with custom command that is used in both PDF compilation, and with MathJax. This file needs to contain only macro definitions, it cannot contain any other LaTeX commands.

Here is an update sample file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\input{mymacros}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 p_{i-1} &= -(p_{i})' - \theta p_i  \myspace \text{if} \hspace{10pt} i=n
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

You can see that it uses the `\myspace` command, and that it includes the `mymacros` file. This file can look like this:

```
\newcommand\myspace{\quad}
```

Now you need to tell TeX4ht to use this file for MathJax, which can be done using the new `MathJaxMacros` configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{MathJaxMacros}{mymacros.tex}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It produces a following HTML:

```
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>\(\newcommand\myspace{\quad}
\) \begin {align*}  p_{i-1} &amp;= -(p_{i})' - \theta p_i \myspace \text {if} \hspace {10pt} i=n  \end {align*}
</p>
```

Which is rendered in this way:

[image]